# language-neutral recursive takeown

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, batch

In `.bat` files for Windows's cmd.exe, recursively taking ownership of a folder's content goes

```
takeown /f foldername /r /d Y >nul: 2>&1
```

Problem is, it works only if in the current locale the word for *Yes* starts with the letter `Y`. E.g. it fails in French, which uses *Oui*, thus requires `O`.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `COPY` command to determine the "yes" response used by the machine.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims=(/ tokens=2" %%Y in (
  '"copy /-y nul "%~f0" <nul"'
) do if not defined yes set "yes=%%Y"
takeown /f foldername /r /d %yes% >nul 2>&1
```

The `%yes%` value will be the entire word, not just the first letter. I think that will work just fine. But if I am wrong, you can simply use `%yes:~0,1%` instead.

**Update**
As fgrieu points out in his comment, the above will fail if the script path includes `(`. Failure due to other special characters could be fixed by ditching the outer double quotes and escaping the redirection. But the `(` is problematic.

Here is an alternate strategy that works as long as `%temp%` points to a valid folder that the user has write privileges. It creates a file with a name known not to cause problems. If the file already exists in `%temp%` then it is undisturbed.

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "%temp%"
if not exist getYes.tmp (call ) >>getYes.tmp
set "yes="
for /f "delims=(/ tokens=2" %%Y in (
  '"copy /-y nul getYes.dummy <nul"'
) do if not defined yes set "yes=%%Y"
takeown /f foldername /r /d %yes% >nul 2>&1
```

I suppose there is no guarantee that COPY and TAKEOWN use the same yes response, but I would be shocked if they don't.

Comment: Clever hack; but I fear it will fail if the bat file's name or one of it's parent's directory includes special characters, including but not limited to `(`. Also this assumes localization of takeown.exe is the same as that from cmd.exe. In this line of thought, we could parse takeown's help obtained line by line with `@for /f "delims= " %%L in ('takeown /?') do @ `and pray that the first occurrence of a `"?"` following `/D` is the local for `"Y"`. Oh my..

Comment: @fgrieu - Good catch with ( in the path. See my update for a solution to that issue. I would be willing to take my chances that TAKEOWN and COPY use the same affirmative response. I think it is highly unlikely that a universal parsing expression could be formulated to extract the affirmative response from the TAKEOWN help.